# save data in local storage in notification arrives when app is not running yet in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-notifications

I have a problem in storing data locally when push notification arrives and the app is not running. It works fine when the app is running or in background.

Comment: what is "storing data locally"? Do you want to save data to `SharedPreferences`, write it in a file, something else..?

Comment: I am storing data in sqlite database.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Getting a `Context` to access the database?

Comment: Thanks Droidman, now i am accessing my class where i put my implementation to store data locally. But facing another problem, "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DatabaseTables at DataSource". Here DataSource is my class where i have logic to store data. I think it is unable to find that class in DataSource.

Comment: do you have Instant Run on? It may cause this kind of issues. Try to clean & rebuild the project

Comment: Please provide your code andlogcat

Answer (score -3):

just check this thing inside manifest .. this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission android:name="net.simplifiedcoding.androidgcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="net.simplifiedcoding.androidgcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application>


<!-- GCM Receiver -->
-<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" android:exported="true">-<intent-filter><action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/><category android:name="com.gnirt69.gcmexample"/></intent-filter></receiver>
<!-- GCM Receiver Service -->
-<service android:name=".GCMPushReceiverService" android:exported="false">-<intent-filter><action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/></intent-filter></service>
<!-- GCM Registration Intent Service -->
-<service android:name=".GCMRegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false">-<intent-filter><action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/></intent-filter></service>-<receiver android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">-<intent-filter>
<!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/><category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app"/></intent-filter></receiver>
```

Comment: Sorry Vikash, I did not get your point. Can you please elaborate which permission are you talking about?